# Unable to load the requested file: login_view.php

Tags: codeigniter

i am facing an error Unable to load the requested file: login_view.php. i have a login controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
 }

 function index()
 {
   $this->load->helper(array('form'));
   $this->load->view('login_view');
 }

}

?>
```

and a view that is being loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</title>
 </head>
 <body>

   <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
   <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
     <label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
     <br/>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" size="20" id="password" name="password"/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**VerifyLogin Page**

```
class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller 
{
     function __construct() 
     { 
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
     }

     function index()
     { 
         $this->load->library('form_validation'); 
         if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
         { 
              $this->load->view('login_view');
         } else
           { 
                redirect('home', 'refresh');
            }
      } 
}
```

please guide me. thanks.

Comment: here is the code for verifylogin as well.

Comment: <?php 
class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {
  function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
 }
 function index()
 {
 $this->load->library('form_validation');
 
   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
    $this->load->view('login_view');
   }
   else
   {
 redirect('home', 'refresh');
}
}

Comment: Just a note: Only the first letter of class and file name should be upper case. As explained here. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that the view you are trying to load doesn't exist in the default "view" location. Did you place it in a sub-directory? Did you edit the view folder location in the config?

Comment: Hello please check your login_view file name and also check  login_view file under in view folder.

Comment: i have extracted code igniter in htdocs.. and placed my view in application/view directory

Comment: its done.. thank you guys. now i have encountered another problem. when i am entering username and password in the fields. its not going to user home page. it remains on the login page , although the username and password are valid in the database

Comment: In your controller, you're running checking for form validation, but you haven't validated any of the fields. So form_validation->run() is going to return false.